# Which PayPal integration for back office && front end E-Commerce solution

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, payment-processing

I am not sure this is best fitted for SO but I couldn't think of a better place to ask.

We have a back office and eCommerce solution. Other integrations we have with SagePay etc allow us to take payments on the website and perform refunds, authorisations etc. via the back office system. Is there a PayPal API that supports this?

Looking at the various API's I can see that Payflow Pro seems to be along the lines of what I need but does this still support payments via paypal accounts?

Also, with the PayPal integration, is there a solution that doesn't require the user to leave the website? If so, how would this work with paying from their PayPal account as they obviously need to log in to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PayPal has plenty of API's to handle all of this.

PayFlow is indeed what you're after, but they've recently changed this to be called [Payments Pro](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wpp) (which is a little confusing because the "old" Payments Pro used the DoDirectPayment API.)

As it stands today, though, when you sign up for Payments Pro they'll put you into the PayFlow platform.  You can use [Express Checkout for PayFlow](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf) to add the PayPal option to your checkout.

With that setup people could choose to pay with a credit card and enter details directly on your site, or they could choose to pay with PayPal and would redirect through PayPal as expected.

If you want to provide users with the ability to process payments without redirecting and logging again, you can use [Reference Transactions](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/about_reference_transactions.htm) or [Preapproved Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/Preapproval-api-operation).

I actually wrote [an article for PayPal covering these options](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments) that you might be interested in taking a look at.

Comment: OK that sounds good. Just to confirm, this platform will still allow me to process transactions via the back office software as well (refunds etc) and also, it is compatible with SOAP (I don't know which feeds PayPal does SOAP with.